# Expression transformation is failing to load data

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have written a simple expression transformation where the mapping concatenates the first and last name and based on salary of the customer it stores the string high,low or medium into the target table.

The workflow is validated and there are no errors. But when the workflow is started it reads the rows from the database and then applies the transformation and then tries to load the target table. Here while loading the data into the target table it doesn't move forward and gets struck and after long time when Integration service gets disconnected it throws a repository error.

The interesting thing is when I run some other workflows it doesn't give any error. Below are the session logs:

---

```
<pre><code>
DIRECTOR> TM_6014 Initializing session [s_mp_person_exp_person] at [Thu Feb 

18 22:21:21 2016].
DIRECTOR> TM_6683 Repository Name: [infa_training]
DIRECTOR> TM_6684 Server Name: [infa_training_IS]

DIRECTOR> TM_6686 Folder: [training]
DIRECTOR> TM_6685 Workflow: [wf_person_exp_person] Run Instance Name: [] Run Id: [38]
DIRECTOR> TM_6101 Mapping name: mp_person_exp_person.
DIRECTOR> TM_6964 Date format for the Session is [MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US]
DIRECTOR> TM_6708 Using configuration property [EnableDataEncryption,no]
DIRECTOR> TM_6708 Using configuration property [StoreHAPersistenceInDB,no]

DIRECTOR> TM_6703 Session [s_mp_person_exp_person] is run by 64-bit Integration Service  [node01_Gizmo], version [9.6.1], build [0606].
MANAGER> PETL_24058 Running Partition Group [1].
MANAGER> PETL_24000 Parallel Pipeline Engine initializing.
MANAGER> PETL_24001 Parallel Pipeline Engine running.
MANAGER> PETL_24003 Initializing session run.
MAPPING> CMN_1569 Server Mode: [ASCII]
MAPPING> CMN_1570 Server Code page: [MS Windows Latin 1 (ANSI), superset of Latin1]
MAPPING> TM_6151 The session sort order is [Binary].
MAPPING> TM_6156 Using low precision processing.
MAPPING> TM_6180 Deadlock retry logic will not be implemented.
MAPPING> TM_6187 Session target-based commit interval is [10000].
MAPPING> TM_6307 DTM error log disabled. 
MAPPING> TE_7022 TShmWriter: Initialized
MAPPING> TM_6007 DTM initialized successfully for session [s_mp_person_exp_person]
DIRECTOR> PETL_24033 All DTM Connection Info: [<NONE>].
MANAGER> PETL_24004 Starting pre-session tasks. : (Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016)
MANAGER> PETL_24027 Pre-session task completed successfully. : (Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016)
DIRECTOR> PETL_24006 Starting data movement.
MAPPING> TM_6660 Total Buffer Pool size is 1219648 bytes and Block size is 65536 bytes.
READER_1_1_1> DBG_21438 Reader: Source is [orcl], user [kakarrot]
READER_1_1_1> BLKR_16003 Initialization completed successfully.
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8147 Writer: Target is database [orcl], user [target], bulk mode [OFF]
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8124 Target Table PERSON :SQL INSERT statement:
INSERT INTO PERSON(ID,FULLNAME,TOTALSAL,ANNUALSAL,CITY,STATE,MOB,SALSTATUS)  VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8124 Target Table PERSON :SQL UPDATE statement:
UPDATE PERSON SET FULLNAME = ?, TOTALSAL = ?, ANNUALSAL = ?, CITY = ?, STATE = ?, MOB = ?, SALSTATUS = ? WHERE ID = ?
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8124 Target Table PERSON :SQL DELETE statement:
DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID = ?
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8270 Target connection group #1 consists of target(s) [PERSON]
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8003 Writer initialization complete.
READER_1_1_1> BLKR_16007 Reader run started.
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8005 Writer run started.
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8158 

*****START LOAD SESSION*****

Load Start Time: Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016

Target tables:

     PERSON


READER_1_1_1> RR_4010 SQ instance [SQ_PERSON] SQL Query [SELECT kakarrot.Person.ID, kakarrot.Person.FNAME, kakarrot.Person.LNAME, kakarrot.Person.SALPERMONTH, kakarrot.Person.COMMISION, kakarrot.Person.CITY, kakarrot.Person.STATE, kakarrot.Person.MOB FROM kakarrot.Person]
READER_1_1_1> RR_4049 SQL Query issued to database : (Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016)
READER_1_1_1> RR_4050 First row returned from database to reader : (Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016)
READER_1_1_1> BLKR_16019 Read [6] rows, read [0] error rows for source table [Person] instance name [PERSON]
READER_1_1_1> BLKR_16008 Reader run completed.
TRANSF_1_1_1> DBG_21216 Finished transformations for Source Qualifier [SQ_PERSON]. Total errors [0] 
WRITER_1_*_1> WRT_8167 Start loading table [PERSON] at: Thu Feb 18 22:21:21 2016
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 08:01:22 2016]
REP_12014 An error occurred while accessing the repository
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 08:01:23 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error (Connection to the Repository Service [infa_training] is broken.)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 08:01:23 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error ([REP_55101] Connection to the Repository Service [infa_training] is broken.)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 08:01:23 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error ([REP_55114] Reconnecting to the Repository Service [infa_training]. The resilience time is 180 seconds.)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 08:01:50 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error ([REP_51490] Communication with client application on host [169.254.164.2] and port [6013] has failed because of network errors. [System Error (errno = 10054): Unknown error].)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:14 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error ([REP_55112] Unable to connect to the Repository Service [infa_training] since the resilience time is up.)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:14 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error (Failed to connect to repository service [infa_training].)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:14 2016]
REP_12014 An error occurred while accessing the repository
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:14 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error (Failed to connect to repository service [infa_training].)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:14 2016]
REP_12400 Repository Error ([REP_55102] Failed to connect to repository service [infa_training].)
CMN_1761 Timestamp Event: [Fri Feb 19 10:00:15 2016]
PETL_24074 Failed to send updates to the master service process. Session run 

`will be terminated.`


</pre></code>
```

---

[image]

Hope you guys can shed light on this problem.

Comment: 1. It has only couple of expression transformations 2) I don't think the target table is locked by other transaction 3) I tried again and this time it executed but it took 2hours just to transfer 6 rows of data to the target table. Here are the logs: http://www.filedropper.com/issuelogs

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Why does a simple expression transformation take 2 hours to load the rows into the target table ??

Comment: My guess is there's something wrong on the database side. Can you replace the Oracle target with a flat file one and run the mapping to confirm it?

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz Yup, it worked using files....The moment workflow is started data loaded onto the file almost immediately but not sure why my specific table in oracle database is not working when other tables work fine.

Comment: No there are no triggers. It only has a primary key constraint.

Comment: Run an INSERT statement (similar to the one generated by PowerCenter) in SQL Developer. Is there any delay?

Answer (score 0):

The issue definitely appears to be with the database.  According to your log, the session hung for 10 hours and then seems to have lost its connection to the repository database as well.  You should try changing the target connection to a flat file and/or any other database you have access to in order to test the session itself.  Also, if you don't have the ability to do it yourself, you should ask a DBA to look at the session as it is running to see why the oracle connection is waiting/hung up.